# Iterate over first N elements of c++11 std::array

Tags: c++11

I am using a std::array (c++11). I am choosing to use a std::array because I want the size to be fixed at compile time (as opposed to runtime). Is there anyway I can iterate over the first N elements ONLY. i.e. something like:

```
std::array<int,6> myArray = {0,0,0,0,0,0};
std::find_if(myArray.begin(), myArray.begin() + 4, [](int x){return (x%2==1);});
```

This is not the best example because find_if returns an iterator marking the FIRST odd number, but you get the idea (I only want to consider the first N, in this case N=4, elements of my std::array).

Note: There are questions similar to this one, but the answer always involves using a different container (vector or valarray, which is not what I want. As I described early, I want to size of the container to be fixed at compile time).

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question and your goals, you want to get *all* odd numbers of the N first elements in the array? You could use [`std::transform`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) for that. Otherwise, just use a normal `for` loop and iterate over N elements?

Comment: Can't you just put that `std::find_if` in a function where `4` is a parameter?

Comment: Why do you think the answer would be different when you use a different container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the way you presented your question, I assume that you *say* "iterate over", but actually *mean* "operate on with an algorithm".

**The behaviour is not specific to a container, but to the iterator type of the container.**

[`std::array::iterator_type`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) satisfies [RandomAccessIterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/RandomAccessIterator), the same as `std::vector` and `std::deque`.

That means that, given

```
std::array<int,6> myArray = {0,0,0,0,0,0};
```

and

```
auto end = myArray.begin() // ...
```

you can add a number `n` to it...

```
auto end = myArray.begin() + 4;
```

...resulting in an iterator to one element *beyond* the `n`th element in the array. As that is the very *definition* for an `end` iterator for the sequence,

```
std::find_if(myArray.begin(), myArray.begin() + 4, ... )
```

works just fine. A somewhat more intuitive example:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

#define N 4

int main()
{
    std::array<char, 6> myArray = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f' };
    auto end = myArray.begin() + N;
    if ( std::find( myArray.begin(), end, 'd' ) != end )
    {
        std::cout << "Found.\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This finds the 4th element in the array, and prints "Found."

Change `#define N 4` to `#define N 3`, and it prints nothing.

Of course, this is assuming that your array *has* `N` elements. If you aren't sure, check `N <= myArray.size()` first and use `myArray.end()` instead if required.

---

For completeness:

- A [BidirectionalIterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/BidirectionalIterator) (`list`, `set`, `multiset`, `map`, `multimap`) only supports `++` and `--`.
- A [ForwardIterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/ForwardIterator) (`forward_list`, `unordered_set`, `unordered_multiset`, `unordered_map`, `unordered_multimap`) only supports `++`.
- An [InputIterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/InputIterator) does not support dereferencing the result of postfix `++`.

Comment: Can you also clarify what question it is that you're answering? When reading the OP's post again, I don't see how this answers his question. (It is a good, informed answer but not sure what *question* it answers!). Also constants as defined with `#define` should very likely be avoided.

Comment: @Tobias: How to iterate over the first N elements of C11 `std::array`. You know, the *title* of the question. ;-)

Comment: So why are you using `std::find`...?

Comment: @Tobias: Because it is close to the OP's example, but simpler and easier to verify than his lambda. (I am assuming that OP *says* "iterate" but *means* "operate on with an algorithm", due to the example he gave and  accompanying text.)

Comment: Using e.g. `myArray.begin() + N` only works if the size of the array is at least N, otherwise it will be beyond `myArray.end()`.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Err... yes?

Comment: Then the iteration will go beyond the end of the array, and into the land of undefined behavior.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Yes, this is obvious. (I accounted for this in my example -- but really, you know about these constraints at compile-time).

Comment: It might be a good idea to explain it in the answer? Especially if N is not a compile-time constant but a value given as input from a user.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: *sigh* That is why we cannot have good things. ;-) Added a note to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to iterate over the first N numbers of a `std::array`, just do something like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

int main() {
    constexpr const int N = 4;
    std::array<int, 6> arr{ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    for (auto it = std::begin(arr); it != std::begin(arr) + N && it != std::end(arr); ++it)
        std::cout << *it << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With C++20, a `std::span` can be used to create a subset view of a `std::array` much like `std::string_view` does for `std::string`. The span replaces maintaining the variable 'N' for the number of sub-elements.

```
auto part = std::span(myArray).first(4);

std::find_if(part.begin(), part.end(), [](int x) {return (x % 2 == 1); });
```

A `std::span` offers many other benefits. It can be used in range based `for` loops. And by using `std::span.subspan`, a span can view any range of elements, not limited to just the first N. A span can also be used not just with `std::array`, but also with C arrays, `std::vector`, and other contiguous containers.